# Output shape of numpy's rfft function

Tags: fft, numpy

For numpy's rfft function, the length of the output is about half of N, the length of the input sequence. What is the reason behind this? What are the frequency bins?

Answer (score 1):

[Check out the numpy docs.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html)

To sum up, real DFT normally takes a `real input` of `N` samples and returns a `complex` output of `N/2+1` values.

What you end up with are the positive frequencies (up to the Nyquist frequency) and the
negative frequencies, which are just complex conjugates of their positive counterparts, are discarded or are not even computed.